# Grab value between "A=" and "&" but even when "&" isnt there

Tags: c

The script below will extract the value between

**A=** and **&**

but if "&" is not present.. then it will fail to extract what is after

A=

how to fix this problem ?

The script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *s = "A=apple&";

    const char *PATTERN1 = "A=";
    const char *PATTERN2 = "&";

    char *target = NULL;
    char *start, *end;

    if ( start = strstr( s, PATTERN1 ) )
    {
        start += strlen( PATTERN1 );
        if ( end = strstr( start, PATTERN2 ) )
        {
            target = ( char * )malloc( end - start + 1 );
            memcpy( target, start, end - start );
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }
    }

    if ( target ) printf( "%s\n", target );

    free( target );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strstr` returns NULL if pattern not found. Use this information and create an `else` branch for that `if ( end = strstr( start, PATTERN2 ) )`

Answer (score 2):

When we've found `end` like this:

```
end = strstr( start, PATTERN2 )
```

Then we currently do nothing if it's null.  Instead of doing nothing, we should set `end` to point at the terminating NUL of the input string:

```
if (!end)
    end = start + strlen(start);
```

And then we can copy in the same way as before:

```
target = malloc(end - start + 1);
memcpy(target, start, end - start);
target[end - start] = '\0';
```

(Note: I've removed the useless and harmful cast of `malloc()`)

---

Full worked example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *s = "A=apple&";

    const char *const PATTERN1 = "A=";
    const char *const PATTERN2 = "&";

    char *start = strstr(s, PATTERN1);
    if (!start) {
        printf("%s not found", PATTERN1);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    start += strlen(PATTERN1);
    char *end = strstr(start, PATTERN2);
    if (!end)
        end = start + strlen(start);
    char *target = malloc(end - start + 1);
    memcpy(target, start, end - start);
    target[end - start] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", target);

    free(target);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```